# Use system borders but default titlebar in chromium/chromium based browsers

Tags: google-chrome, chromium, brave

So I'm using brave, and currently have the "Use system title bar and borders" option on, since the default border is pretty ugly in my opinion.

I was wondering if it is possible to use the system borders, but keep the default title bar. I find it annoying that you can only turn both on or off as the system title bar is placed on top of the window, taking up an unnecessary amount space while the default one is integrated into the application.

The title bar is possible to style with GTK themes, but the borders are not (at least as far as i know), so this would be useful if it's possible. I doubt it though since the options are toggled by the single "chrome_custom_frame" property in the preferences file.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know – no. If an X11 window opts out of the "window decorations", it opts out of *both* the borders and the title bar at once.

However, when system borders are enabled, both of them are drawn by the same component (the window manager) and both are themed as a single unit in pretty much every WM that I've used.

(In the case of GNOME Shell, the GTK3 theme (gtk.css) defines style for both the "server-side" titlebar and borders. Other window managers have their own theme formats.)